# Trying to change Character set for Apache2

Tags: php, html, apache, apache2

Okay, so I'm not sure if Apache2 is the reason probably not. But maybe...
I'm trying to set the character set to "ISO-8859-1". When I have data send from my server to the client that contains letters such as ÆØÅ they display, but when I just write it in like a header in HTML not working.

So what I've tried is adding meta charset="ISO-8859-1" to the page. 
I've tried default_charset = "ISO-8859-1" to php.ini
I've added AddDefaultCharset ISO-8859-1 to apache2.conf

If I open the document from my desktop and into Chrome it works fine, but not when I load it from the server it won't display the letters correctly.

Okay turns out that if I echo the letters in the index.php ÆØÅ, It doesn't show up. But if I do it's in another file it shows up sometimes.

Source code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>9Chat - Pure Chill</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="Assets/logo.png" method="post">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Velkommen</h1>
    <h2>Vælg dit navn</h2>

    <form method="post" action="navigation.php">
        <input type="text" name="nickname" value="Kaldenavn">
        <input type="password" name="id" value="xxxxxx">
        <input type="submit" value="Tilslut">
    </form>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/WebSocket.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    @import url('Styles/login_page.css')
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried to add `<meta charset="iso-8859-1">` in the `<head>` of your HTML? Did you make sure your rebooted your apache server after making the modifications?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work either... And yes I did make sure to restart my apache server.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: Is the source file in this very encoding?

Comment: Updated the thread with something I just discovered